# What does "award a tender" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "Egypt decided to increase the supplies for 2017" or "Egypt held a bid and Qatar won the bid to supply LNG to Egypt"? http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tender_2

"Egypt last year awarded a large tender for 2017 supplies, much of it sourced from Qatar, although traders said rising domestic output and alternative sources including Norway, Nigeria and the United States could fill a potential gap."

Source: http://af.reuters.com/article/egyptNews/idAFL3N1J220N

Comment: _"Egypt last year awarded a large tender for 2017 supplies, much of it sourced from Qatar"_ means that last year, Egypt decided how much they would need for this year, and other countries bidded to meet that demand - with Qatar being a significant provider (i.e. kind of your second definition, but not _just_ Qatar).

Comment: Those who were *awarded the contract* to supply Egypt with LNG are sourcing much of it from Qatar.

Answer (score 1):

One definition of *tender* from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tender):

> : something that may be offered in payment; specifically : money

Replace the words "awarded a large tender" with "paid a lot of money" and I think it helps to easily decipher the precise meaning that was intended here. The former phrase does have the additional connotation that contractual agreements are *most likely* involved, but at base, it really does simply mean that Egypt paid a lot of money for supplies in 2017, and they got most of those supplies from Qatar.

Note that I believe the source contains a grammatical error that makes it more difficult to understand. No matter what you interpret "award" or "tender" to mean, clearly those things came from Egypt and were not "sourced" from Qatar. For this reason, "much of it" is incorrect. There's no correct or logical antecedent for "it" in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean "Egypt decided to increase the supplies for 2017"

That would be the motivation for setting up a bidding process, so that would reflect what happened prior to the action in the article.

> "Egypt held a bid and Qatar won the bid to supply LNG to Egypt"

This interpretation comes close but misses a nuance or two in the meanings.

"Tender" refers to Egypt asking for bids, and the "award" refers to Egypt making a decision and giving the business to someone.

"Sourced from Qatar" doesn't necessarily mean Qatar won the award, it could mean they will be a predominant supplier to whoever won (the winner being more of a broker).

"Award" doesn't necessarily define the process that led to it. For example, there could have been a request for bids, then graft and corruption led to the award going to someone other than the lowest bidder (I'm not suggesting that happened, only the inaccuracy of interpreting the meaning that way). "Award" really just refers to the decision of giving it to someone.

So your second interpretation sort of captures the essence of the meaning, but isn't precise.